# Автоматическое закрытие UIView

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios

Как сделать, чтобы при клике за пределами UIView, эта вьюшка скрывалась (неважно removeFromSuperview или setFrame). Проблема в том, что UIView не может отлавливать событие click-outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отлавливай клик на том, что за пределами UIView, например создай UIButton с кастомным стилем (она будет прозрачная) и подложи ее **под** твой UIView, ну а для этого баттона определи обработку click-inside, по которому и скрывай UIView...

Upd: Вариант второй.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.view 
action:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.superview addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
[gestureRecognizer release];
```

Comment: Поддерживаю, это единственный возможный способ.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё можно отлавливать касания на superview, что-то типа такого (sampleView - Ваш UIView):

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
CGPoint firstTouch =[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(sampleView.frame, firstTouch))
    [sampleView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Но для этого нужно отнаследоваться или написать категорию...

Comment: Зачем? Это пишется не в том виде который закрывается, а в superview или его контроллере, только что пробовал

Comment: да, я просто не думал что контроллер тоже от респондера наследуется...