# MonoTouch - Как добавить к UIView событие "Touch Up Outside" ?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, monotouch, ios

Как добавить к UIView событие "Touch Up Outside" ?

Или его слушатель?

Задача стоит в простом закрытии всплывающего списка, если происходит тач за его пределами.

На крайний случай пойдет объяснение и на Objective-C.

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для obj-c уже было: [автоматическое закрытие UIView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4075/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-uiview).

Comment: Спасибо, уже читал.